# how to set random text size on each letter once? (processing)

Tags: random, processing, text-size

how can I set a random size for each letter that spreads out? I want each of them to have a different random size but I can't really figure out where to put `textSize (random(10, 20));` because if I put it under draw it just loops over and over again that each frame the text size of each letter changes but when I put it under setup it just changes the size of all the letters.

```java
String message = "Alice fell into the rabbit hole";
int x =  130;
int y = 90;

Letter[] letters;

void setup() {
  size(260, 200);
  letters = new Letter[message.length()];
  textSize (random(10, 20));

  for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) { 
    letters[i] = new Letter(x, y, message.charAt(i));
    //x += textWidth(message.charAt(i));
  }
}

void draw() { 
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) { 
    letters[i].display(); 
    letters[i].shake();
  }
}

class Letter {
  char letter;
  float x, y;

  Letter (float x, float y, char letter) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.letter = letter;
  }

  void display() {
    fill(0);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    text(letter, x, y);
  }

  void shake() {
    x += random(-2, 2);
    y += random(-2, 2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Letter` class encapsulates everything about a specific letter. So if you want a random size for each letter, then you'd store that size in the `Letter` class.

If you want the size to be the same for a single letter throughout the lifetime of the program, then you'd set that size in the constructor.

Then you would use that size in the `display()` function before you draw the letter.

Comment: oh okay i'll try that

Comment: can I ask where and what a constructor is? :)

Comment: @Noobprocessor Have you tried googling it? Hint: your class already contains a constructor.

Comment: okay got what it means! took me a day lol! what do you mean I use the size in the `display()` function before a draw the letter? :)

Comment: @Noobprocessor What have you tried? What do you think I mean? Right now you're only setting the text size once, and every letter uses that size. It sounds like you want to set the text size for every letter. How do you think you would do that?

Comment: nvm i got it already!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank youuu!